# USI regex needed

Tags: regex

I'm trying to add a regex for unique student identifier. USI must contain only capital letters, all characters except O and I and digits 2-9.

i tried this regex but it is not working

```js
[^IO,^01]+$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That regex can be:

```
^[2-9A-HJ-NP-Z]+$
```

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks mate

Comment: Hi anubhava ,  can we set a limit to 10 characters string only for USI number

Comment: Yes sure, use: `^[2-9A-HJ-NP-Z]{1,10}$`

Comment: yes, it is working with 1 or 10 characters, i change it a little bit to 
^[2-9A-HJ-NP-Z]{10}$   so it contains exact 10 characters.

Comment: Yes indeed, for exact 10 use: `^[2-9A-HJ-NP-Z]{10}$`

Comment: marked it to complete. much appreciated. Thank you so much.